# Prove by induction $ \sin x + \sin 2x + ... + \sin nx = \frac {\sin (\frac {n + 1} {2} x)} {\sin \frac{x}{2}} \sin \frac{nx}{2} $

Tags: calculus, induction

> Prove by induction 
>   $$ \sin x + \sin 2x + ... + \sin nx = \frac {\sin (\frac {n + 1} {2} x)} {\sin \frac{x}{2}} \sin \frac{nx}{2} $$

What I have for now:
$$  \frac {\sin (\frac {n + 1} {2} x)} {\sin \frac{x}{2}} \sin \frac{nx}{2} + \sin(n + 1)x =  \frac {\sin (\frac {n + 2} {2} x)} {\sin \frac{x}{2}} \sin \frac{(n + 1)x}{2}$$
Letting $y = \frac {(n + 1)x} {2} $

$$\frac {\sin y} {\sin \frac{x}{2}} \sin (y - \frac{x}{2}) + \sin2y = 
\frac {\sin (y + \frac {x} {2} )} {\sin \frac{x}{2}} \sin y $$

Then I used $\sin (\alpha + \beta)$ and $\sin (\alpha - \beta)$ formulas, bit they didn't help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are almost there, but use $\sin 2y = 2\sin y\cos y$, considering your left hand side we get:

$$\frac {\sin y} {\sin \frac{x}{2}} \sin (y - \frac{x}{2}) + \sin2y  = 
\frac {\sin y} {\sin \frac{x}{2}} \sin (y - \frac{x}{2}) + 2\sin y\cos y = $$
$$\left(\frac {\sin (y-\frac{x}{2})} {\sin \frac{x}{2}} +2\cos y\right)\sin y = \left(\frac {\sin (y-\frac{x}{2}) +2\cos y\sin\frac{x}{2}} {\sin \frac{x}{2}}\right)\sin y =$$
Now use the subtraction of angles formula $\sin (\alpha-\beta)$:
$$=\left(\frac {\sin y\cos \frac{x}{2} - \cos y \sin \frac{x}{2} +2\cos y\sin\frac{x}{2}} {\sin \frac{x}{2}}\right)\sin y = \left(\frac {\sin y\cos \frac{x}{2} +\cos y\sin\frac{x}{2}} {\sin \frac{x}{2}}\right)\sin y =$$
And lastly use the addition of angles formula $\sin(\alpha+\beta)$:
$$=\left(\frac {\sin (y+ \frac{x}{2}) } {\sin \frac{x}{2}}\right)\sin y $$
Which is what you had on your right hand side, and thus the induction is done.

Answer (score 6):

You can also see that
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{n}\sin kx & =\Im \sum_{k=0}^{n}\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}kx}\\
& = \Im \sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}x}\right)^k\\
& = \Im\frac{\left(\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}x}\right)^{n+1}-1}{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}x}-1}\\
& = \Im\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}(n+1)x}-1}{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}x}-1}\\
& = \Im\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\frac{n+1}{2}x}}{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\frac{x}{2}}}\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\frac{n+1}{2}x}-\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\frac{n+1}{2}x}}{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\frac{x}{2}}-\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\frac{x}{2}}}\\
& = \Im\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\frac{nx}{2}}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{n+1}{2}x\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}\\
& = \sin\left(\frac{nx}{2}\right)\frac{\sin\left(\frac{n+1}{2}x\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}.
\end{align}

Comment: This is not induction, but a direct (maybe easier) way to derive the equality.

Comment: Also we can obtain the same result for the cos.

Comment: @HamedBaghalGhaffari Indeed! This is also a way to compute the Dirichlet's kernel, in particular used for Fourier's series.

Comment: Yes it is which is not good kernel. My master's thesis had some kernels like this.